# How to send joined table data through form collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int DesignationID { get; set; }

    public virtual Designation Designation { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public void AccountUpdate(Employee employee) {}
```

View:-

```
<label name= "Name"> Peter </label>
<label name= "DesignationName"> Manager </label>
```

I am sending **Form Collection** object to my **AccountUpdate** action method, I am getting **Employee Name** BUT not its **designation name**.
Can you tell me how can I access the designation name in Action method in employee object

Thanks

Comment: Your view just shows `<label>` elements. Show how you generate the form controls for the properties of `Employee`. And why are you adding a `name` attribute (its not a valid attribute for `label`)

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC model binding requires properties on your model to exactly match your field on the web page. So you either need to change the model property name to match the field name:

```
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int DesignationID { get; set; }

    public virtual Designation DesignationName { get; set; }
}
```

or the field name to match the model property name:

```
<label name= "Name"> Peter </label>
<label name= "Designation"> Manager </label>
```

Alternatively, if the `Designation` type is a complex object that can't be directly converted from a `string`, you will need to either implement a custom model binder and/or type converter ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15499089/mvc-custom-type-property-is-not-binding-in-my-model)).

Comment: Is it good approach to add another property to Employee class as you have suggested ?

Comment: @FahadMeraj You don't need to add another property, just rename an existing one.

Comment: Now I am getting the object in designation but cant access or set its value "Manager"

Answer (score 1):

[How do I create/use a form and model-binder to pass collections from View => Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24515202/how-do-i-create-use-a-form-and-model-binder-to-pass-collections-from-view-con)

To list a model property that is a collection of objects of another class, try this:

```
public class Person {
   public int ID { get; set;}
   public string Name { get; set;}
   public List<Car> Cars { get; set;}
}

public class Car {
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string name { get; set;}
}
```

In view, you must list the car objects from person object as inputs named with the property name and a index

```
@model Person
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    for(int i = 0; i < Model.Cars.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Cars[i].ID)
        ....
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Grant Access" />
}
```

Using this, your model automatically populate the property Cars with the inputs sent from the form

Comment: I am new here, so I do not know many things 

I replied to my question only so that  it can be helpful to others,
but in return I got down vote :)

Comment: You probably got a down vote because this is not the way to do it and is poor code. It needs to be `for (int = i; i < Model.Cars.Count; i++) { @Html.HiddenFor(m =< m.Cars[i].name) }` But having a view that only includes hidden inputs for your collection is nonsense anyway.

Comment: well the code may be wrong but it gives you the hint to solve the problem which I have asked in post.
And I found your comment a bit harsh too

Comment: Sorry. Next time I'll just give it the down vote it deserves instead of pointing out your errors and move on.

Comment: Stephen Muecke I admire your effort how you help posters here, you have helped me before.
Next time I would be careful in posting such type of code

Comment: I have edited you answer to show how to generate you collection correctly, but if all you doing is creating hidden inputs, then you should not be doing this. You just degrading performance by sending extra data to the client and posting it all back unchanged, and opening yourself to over-posting attacks. If for any reason you need the collection again in the POST method, just get it from the repository again.

Comment: I really appreciate that, thank you for being so explanatory